# Can someone help identify what software do these 2 icons belong?

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

What are the names of the software these 2 icons belong to? (This is a screenshot of the taskbar from the Windows 10 operating system)

[image]

Comment: A high-res screenshot would be helpful

Comment: As would operating system, applications running at the time. There was not any information included. Also context of other icons nearby.

Comment: What I've provided are all the information available to me... I'm just trying to figure out what software do these 2 icons belong. If one has used these software before, s/he should be able to identify them without much trouble.

Comment: In my Firefox the first one is uBlock Origin. I just right clicked on it to see what it was. It shows 5 blocks on this page. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the left – Fortinet "FortiClient" (enterprise VPN software).

On the right – IBM SPSS Statistics (statistical analysis package).

(I think you should have asked the computer's owner instead...)